# How to divide a number across multiple cells without decimal points but keep the total the same with original Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to divide a number into multiple cells but the total of the divided number will still add up to be the same as original. Please take a look at the following table as example:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this with excel formula? Or is it impossible to achieve with formula alone? Thank you in advance

Comment: So they can be any integers in any order, provided that they sum to the desired total? And all five cells should contain a value, unless this is not possible (as in your example with total 3)?

Comment: if the number is smaller than the divider, will fill the rest of the cells with 0.

Comment: How do you decide what the 'divider' is in each case?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't state it well, the divider is, plainly speaking, the number of column. So for the example above, the divider is 5.

Comment: So why isn't the result for the first row 3|3|3|3|1, for example?

Comment: @JosWoolley, good question. I for one have assumed (possibly wrongfully) that the devide needs to happen as equal as possible based on given sample data.

Comment: Okay, for the first row, if we use the normal excel formula:
13/5 would be 2.6, so if we round it down, it would become 2. Then if we add up 2|2|2|2|2 in total it would become 10, and there are 3 leftover which will get distributed again to each of the cells until it ran out of leftover. Hence why it became 3|3|3|2|2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
=ROUNDDOWN($A2/COUNTA($B$1:$F$1);0)+IF(COUNTA($B$1:B$1)<=($A2-ROUNDDOWN($A2/COUNTA($B$1:$F$1);0)*COUNTA($B$1:$F$1));1;0)
```

[image]

Just drag down and to right manually. Notice my argument separator in formulas is `;` so maybe you need to use `,` depending on your settings

Answer (score 5):

A math based solution could be:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(a,A2:A5/5,IF({1,2,3,4,5}*0.2>MOD(a,1),INT(a),ROUNDUP(a,0)))
```

If you don't want to manually change the reference of `A2:A5`, then:

```
=LET(a,DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1)/5,IF({1,2,3,4,5}*0.2>MOD(a,1),INT(a),ROUNDUP(a,0)))
```

Comment: Hi there, may I know the range of "a" in your formula above?

Comment: @Milanor, that is a variable refering to `A2:A5`

Comment: I see, but I'm a bit confused as for why we need to check for rows, because in this case I only need to make sure that the result of division fills up the 5 columns besides the number (hence the number is rounded from Number/5)

Comment: The reference is needed. How would one otherwise know the content of these cells to begin with? @Milanor

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this area, it seems that after trying out your formula, it only give me #SPILL! error as the result. I tried to convert it to array based formula afterwards (with Ctrl + Shift + Enter), it worked for 1 cell, but not when I tried to copy paste it around. Something wrong with the way I did it?

Comment: Yes, the error is a hint that other values are in the way of the spilled area. Make sure that `B2:F5` are empty cells to begin with before pasting above formula in `B2` @Milanor

Comment: Okay, I think I made it work but to manually convert the formula to array for each cells seems like gonna be a hell of work to do for a long list of number (like hundreds or thousands). It is outputting the result that I wanted but I think another approach would be needed for long list of numbers.

Comment: @Milanor, what do you mean? A longer list of numbers down column A? You can simply change `A2:A5` to whatever range you need really. Say `A2:A500000` should still work fine. If not this, than please be more clear what you meant with *"manually convert the formula to array for each cell"*.

Comment: I don't know why if I'm not pressing ctrl + shift + enter on each cells, it will show up as #SPILL! error. yeah even after I clear out B5 to F5. That's what I mean by manually convert it to array formula for each cells.

Comment: So your cells are not cleared, simple. Empty cells, = no value whatsoever. Not even empty strings or other invisible characters.

Comment: I have double checked, it's empty and even copy pasting the formula on new sheet. But I still get the same error. I'm using office 365 version of excel though. Not sure if it matters, but I'd like to point it out.

Comment: As per the screenshot you can tell the formula works. So I'm simply not sure what is wrong on your end nomore if not blocking the spilled array @Milanor

Comment: All the cells where you expect the formula to show a value should be cleared. So if you increase the input range, all cells in column B:F in all these rows should be clear. (And you don't need Ctrl+shift+enter in Office 365)